# How to bind an IP address with apache on Windows 7 to host my Joomla web application?

Tags: apache

I have been developing a Joomla based application on my localhost on port 8080. Now what i require is to bind an IP address on Windows 7 running Apache web server so that my Joomla web application can be accessed via the designated IP address in my web browser.

Any clue or guidelines about how to do that? Thank you

Comment: Probably better asked at http://serverfault.com/ ...

Answer (score 6):

Do I understand correctly that you want to make your website on your local computer on the Internet?

Apart from the poor uptime that you will experience with this you will need a number of things:

1) Create a tunnel/ server address of your local computer on your Internet Router. This will also mean you will need a fixed IP address on your local network, not DHCP. Refer to your Router's documentation.

2) Set up a DNS record www.domain.com to your IP address, either your ISP gives you a fixed IP address or you need to use some Dynamic DNS provider.

3) Make sure that Apache listens to your local network IP address.

Ensure you are listening to Port 80 by having

```
Listen 80
```

in ports.conf

Set up Virtual Hosts on your IP address,

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>              
    ServerName www.domain.com

    DocumentRoot c:\localfolder\website

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I currently type localhost:8080/joomla-application-path. What I require is to have live ip i.e. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and my joomla site should load.

Comment: You can do this with my description, but you need to a) have a static IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) and b) you need to map port 8080 on your router to port 80 on your local machine. This is usually called tunnel or private hosting in the router configuration